# как Поставить точку на пересечении двух линий? Canvas js

Tags: javascript, canvas

```
if (window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    let canvas, context, canvaso, contexto;

    // По умолчанию линия - инструмент по умолчанию
    let tool;
    let tool_default = 'line';

    function init() {
        canvaso = document.getElementById('tablet');
        if (!canvaso) {
            alert('Ошибка! Canvas элемент не найден!');
            return;
        }

        if (!canvaso.getContext) {
            alert('Ошибка! canvas.getContext не найден!');
            return;
        }

        contexto = canvaso.getContext('2d');
        if (!contexto) {
            alert('Ошибка! Не могу получить getContext!');
            return;
        }

        let container = canvaso.parentNode;
        canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        if (!canvas) {
            alert('Ошибка! Не могу создать canvas элемент!');
            return;
        }

        canvas.id = 'imageTemp';
        canvas.width = canvaso.width;
        canvas.height = canvaso.height;
        container.appendChild(canvas);

        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Получаем инструмент из option
        let tool_select = document.getElementById('tools');
        if (!tool_select) {
            alert('Ошибка! Элемент tools не найден!');
            return;
        }
        tool_select.addEventListener('change', ev_tool_change, false);

        // Активируем способ рисования по-умолчанию
        if (tools[tool_default]) {
            tool = new tools[tool_default]();
            tool_select.value = tool_default;
        }

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
        canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', ev_canvas, false);
    }



    function ev_canvas(ev) {
        if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) {
            ev._x = ev.layerX;
            ev._y = ev.layerY;
        } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) {
            ev._x = ev.offsetX;
            ev._y = ev.offsetY;
        }


        let func = tool[ev.type];
        if (func) {
            func(ev);
        }
    }

    // Обработчик событий для изменения селекта
    function ev_tool_change(ev) {
        if (tools[this.value]) {
            tool = new tools[this.value]();
        }
    }

    // Эта функция вызывается каждый раз после того, как пользователь
    // завершит рисование. Она очищает imageTemp.
    function img_update() {
        contexto.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    // Содержит реализацию каждого инструмента рисования
    let tools = {};


    // Линия
    tools.line = function () {
        let tool = this;
        this.started = false;

        this.mousedown = function (ev) {
            tool.started = true;
            tool.x0 = ev._x;
            tool.y0 = ev._y;
        };

        this.mousemove = function (ev) {
            if (!tool.started) {
                return;
            }

            context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(tool.x0, tool.y0);
            context.lineTo(ev._x, ev._y);
            context.stroke();
            context.closePath();

        };



        this.mouseup = function (ev) {
            if (tool.started) {
                tool.mousemove(ev);
                tool.started = false;
                img_update();
            }
        };

        if (img_update !== img_update) {
            console.log(1)
        }
    };



    init();

}, false);
```

}

Comment: Я видимо что-то не понял, но где расчёт точки пересечения? После нахождения точки - нарисовать залитую окружность с центром в точке пересечения.

Comment: Я также искал ответ на такой же вопрос. Ответ нашел в этом видео.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RPxMVtXaFyw